# adding arrow icon after every drop in angular drag and drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, styling, drop

I am building a drag and drop list in angular where I want to render 'arrow' (google icon - 'south') after every drop according to a condition. The code I've written is this:

```
<div class="example-box"  
                    *ngFor="let item of workflow; let i = index" 
                    [cdkDragDisabled]="item.disabled" cdkDragLockAxis="y" 
                    cdkDragBoundary=".workflow-zone" cdkDrag 
                    >
                    &nbsp;&nbsp; <mat-icon>{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.value}}
                    <ng-template [ngIf]="!(item.value === 'Start' || item.value === 'Finish')" >
                        <div class="delete-icon" >
                            <button class="button" (click)="onDelete(i);"><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon></button>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                    </div>
                    <div class="arrow-insertion"
                    *ngFor="let item of workflow">
                        <div *ngIf="item.value === 'Start'; then StartBlock else NotStartBlock"></div>
                        <ng-template #StartBlock>
                            <mat-icon>south</mat-icon>
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template #NotStartBlock>
                            <div *ngIf="item.value === 'Finish'; then FinishBlock else NotFinishBlock"></div>
                            <ng-template #FinishBlock>
                                <mat-icon>south</mat-icon>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template #NotFinishBlock>
                                <div *ngIf="item.value === 'Step'; then StepBlock else NotStepBlock"></div>
                                <ng-template #StepBlock>
                                    <mat-icon>south</mat-icon>
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template #NotStepBlock>
                                    <div class="first-two">
                                        <mat-icon>west</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;<mat-icon>east</mat-icon>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="next-two">
                                        <mat-icon>south</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<mat-icon>south</mat-icon>
                                    </div>
                                </ng-template>
                            </ng-template>
                        </ng-template>
                    </div>
```

I have currently made an 'arrow-insertion' div **AFTER** the 'example-box' div. But the arrows are rendered like this: [image: image 1]

and if I place the 'arrow-insertion' div **INSIDE** the 'example-box', it renders like this: [image: image 2]

But I want the arrows to be rendered between each drop, something like this:

```
Start
  |
  V
Step
  |
  V
Finish
```

Can anyone please help me with the same? Thanks

P.S : The start and the finish are always rendered at the start and are not draggable or delete-able, this means that I can only add 'Step' and 'Branch' inside the drop area. I need to render 2 different kinds of arrows for both, for step, it would be just a normal arrow as shown in the images but for branch it would be something like this:

```
   Start
     |
     V
   Step
     |
     V
  -------
  |     |
  V     V
 Step  Step       --This would be branch inserted into the drop. Currently it's shown similar 
  |     |           to 'step' with text reading 'branch' instead of 'step' as the only 
  -------           difference. 
     |
     V
   Finish
```

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz please?

Comment: StackBlitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-a2emn9? Sorry for the non responsiveness of the code, you need to drag the output window a little bit to use drag and drop effectively. @DonaldDuck

Comment: Have you seen the stackBlitz? @DonaldDuck

Comment: Do it all in a single *ngFor, as having two is causing this error. Now you can choose to either add an arrow aswell as the step to workflow when you drop it in, or show the south arrow by default, unless it is the final step, e.g. *ngIf= item.value != finish

Comment: Can you please edit the stackblitz? because when I try to do it, its not resolving the issue, the arrow is still rendered as in the second Image. Thanks

Comment: Are you suggesting that I enter the arrow in the drop itself and style it using css to place it below the text?